# hello world with JMS on Glassfish

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, jms, message-driven-bean, jboss-mdb

Following the JMS example in [Java EE 7 with GlassFish 4 Application Server](http://isbn.directory/book/978-1-78217-688-6), p 203, I can send messages, but but can't seem to receive messages:

sending a message:

```
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ appclient -client NetBeansProjects/MessageSender/dist/MessageSender.jar 
Mar 05, 2015 3:47:05 AM org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version <clinit>
INFO: HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.0.0.Final
Mar 05, 2015 3:47:05 AM com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.ResourceAdapter start
INFO: MQJMSRA_RA1101: GlassFish MQ JMS Resource Adapter: Version:  5.1  (Build 9-b) Compile:  July 29 2014 1229
Mar 05, 2015 3:47:05 AM com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.ResourceAdapter start
INFO: MQJMSRA_RA1101: GlassFish MQ JMS Resource Adapter starting: broker is REMOTE, connection mode is TCP
Mar 05, 2015 3:47:05 AM com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.ResourceAdapter start
INFO: MQJMSRA_RA1101: GlassFish MQ JMS Resource Adapter Started:REMOTE
Sending the following message: Testing, 1, 2, 3. Can you hear me?
Sending the following message: Do you copy?
Sending the following message: Good bye!
thufir@doge:~$
```

waiting to receive the message:

```
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ appclient -client NetBeansProjects/MessageReceiver/dist/MessageReceiver.jar 
Mar 05, 2015 3:48:11 AM org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version <clinit>
INFO: HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.0.0.Final
Mar 05, 2015 3:48:11 AM com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.ResourceAdapter start
INFO: MQJMSRA_RA1101: GlassFish MQ JMS Resource Adapter: Version:  5.1  (Build 9-b) Compile:  July 29 2014 1229
Mar 05, 2015 3:48:11 AM com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.ResourceAdapter start
INFO: MQJMSRA_RA1101: GlassFish MQ JMS Resource Adapter starting: broker is REMOTE, connection mode is TCP
Mar 05, 2015 3:48:11 AM com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.ResourceAdapter start
INFO: MQJMSRA_RA1101: GlassFish MQ JMS Resource Adapter Started:REMOTE
Waiting for messages...
```

message sender:

```
package net.ensode.glassfishbook;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.JMSContext;
import javax.jms.JMSProducer;
import javax.jms.Queue;

public class MessageSender {

    @Resource(mappedName = "jms/CrmConnectionFactory")
    private static ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    @Resource(mappedName = "jms/CrmQueue")
    private static Queue queue;

    public void produceMessages() {

        JMSContext jmsContext = connectionFactory.createContext();
        JMSProducer jmsProducer = jmsContext.createProducer();

        String msg1 = "Testing, 1, 2, 3. Can you hear me?";
        String msg2 = "Do you copy?";
        String msg3 = "Good bye!";

        System.out.println("Sending the following message: "
                + msg1);
        jmsProducer.send(queue, msg1);
        System.out.println("Sending the following message: "
                + msg2);
        jmsProducer.send(queue, msg2);
     System.out.println("Sending the following message: "
                + msg3);
        jmsProducer.send(queue, msg3);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MessageSender().produceMessages();
    }
}
```

message receiver:

```
package net.ensode.glassfishbook;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.JMSConsumer;
import javax.jms.JMSContext;
import javax.jms.Topic;

public class MessageReceiver {

    @Resource(mappedName = "jms/CrmConnectionFactory")
    private static ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
    @Resource(mappedName = "jms/CrmTopic")
    private static Topic topic;

    public void getMessages() {
        String message;
        boolean goodByeReceived = false;

        JMSContext jmsContext = connectionFactory.createContext();
        JMSConsumer jMSConsumer = jmsContext.createConsumer(topic);

        System.out.println("Waiting for messages...");
        while (!goodByeReceived) {
            message = jMSConsumer.receiveBody(String.class);
            if (message != null) {
                System.out.print("Received the following message: ");
                System.out.println(message);
                System.out.println();
                if (message.equals("Good bye!")) {
                    goodByeReceived = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MessageReceiver().getMessages();
    }
}
```

glassfish console:

```
asadmin> 
asadmin> list-jms-resources
jms/CrmQueue
jms/CrmTopic
jms/__defaultConnectionFactory
jms/CrmConnectionFactory
jms/CrmQueueConnectionFactory
jms/CrmTopicConnectionFactory
Command list-jms-resources executed successfully.
asadmin> 
asadmin> version
Version = GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1  (build 13)
Command version executed successfully.
asadmin>
```

glassfish logs:

```
[2015-03-05T02:21:04.258-0800] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler] [tid: _ThreadID=39 _ThreadName=admin-listener(2)] [timeMillis: 1425550864258] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Initiating Jersey application, version Jersey: 2.10.4 2014-08-08 15:09:00...]]

[2015-03-05T02:21:04.321-0800] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-REST-00001] [javax.enterprise.admin.rest] [tid: _ThreadID=39 _ThreadName=admin-listener(2)] [timeMillis: 1425550864321] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Listening to REST requests at context: /command/domain.]]

[2015-03-05T03:42:44.022-0800] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [jts.startup_msg] [javax.enterprise.system.core.transaction.com.sun.jts.CosTransactions] [tid: _ThreadID=46 _ThreadName=iiop-service-kernel(1) SelectorRunner] [timeMillis: 1425555764022] [levelValue: 800] [[
  JTS5014: Recoverable JTS instance, serverId = [3700]]]

[2015-03-05T03:42:45.389-0800] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.resource.jms] [tid: _ThreadID=158 _ThreadName=p: thread-pool-1; w: 1] [timeMillis: 1425555765389] [levelValue: 800] [[
  addresslist.setjmsservice.provider]]

[2015-03-05T03:42:45.390-0800] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.resource.jms] [tid: _ThreadID=158 _ThreadName=p: thread-pool-1; w: 1] [timeMillis: 1425555765390] [levelValue: 800] [[
  jms.connection.url]]

[2015-03-05T03:42:45.568-0800] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.resourceadapter.mqjmsra.lifecycle] [tid: _ThreadID=158 _ThreadName=p: thread-pool-1; w: 1] [timeMillis: 1425555765568] [levelValue: 800] [[
  MQJMSRA_RA1101: GlassFish MQ JMS Resource Adapter: Version:  5.1  (Build 9-b) Compile:  July 29 2014 1229]]

[2015-03-05T03:42:45.569-0800] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.resourceadapter.mqjmsra.lifecycle] [tid: _ThreadID=158 _ThreadName=p: thread-pool-1; w: 1] [timeMillis: 1425555765569] [levelValue: 800] [[
  MQJMSRA_RA1101: GlassFish MQ JMS Resource Adapter starting: broker is EMBEDDED, connection mode is Direct]]

[2015-03-05T03:42:46.816-0800] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.resourceadapter.mqjmsra.lifecycle] [tid: _ThreadID=158 _ThreadName=p: thread-pool-1; w: 1] [timeMillis: 1425555766816] [levelValue: 800] [[
  MQJMSRA_RA1101: GlassFish MQ JMS Resource Adapter Started:EMBEDDED]]

thufir@doge:~$
```

The only modification I made to the code from the book was to the name for the JMS queue and topic.

Comment: I'm trying to get the [jms details from glassfish](http://askubuntu.com/questions/593034/how-to-get-jms-connection-factory-details-from-the-asadmin-cli-for-glassfish) from the asadmin CLI.

Answer (score 0):

At present I cannot explain why this solution works, or is in any way different.  However, it runs correctly:

```
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ appclient -client NetBeansProjects/JMSPTPProducer/dist/JMSPTPProducer.jar 
Mar 08, 2015 4:33:07 AM org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version <clinit>
INFO: HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.0.0.Final
Mar 08, 2015 4:33:08 AM com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.ResourceAdapter start
INFO: MQJMSRA_RA1101: GlassFish MQ JMS Resource Adapter: Version:  5.1  (Build 9-b) Compile:  July 29 2014 1229
Mar 08, 2015 4:33:08 AM com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.ResourceAdapter start
INFO: MQJMSRA_RA1101: GlassFish MQ JMS Resource Adapter starting: broker is REMOTE, connection mode is TCP
Mar 08, 2015 4:33:08 AM com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.ResourceAdapter start
INFO: MQJMSRA_RA1101: GlassFish MQ JMS Resource Adapter Started:REMOTE
Sending the following message: Testing, 1, 2, 3. Can you hear me?
Sending the following message: Do you copy?
Sending the following message: Good bye!
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ appclient -client NetBeansProjects/JMSPTPConsumer/dist/JMSPTPConsumer.jar 
Mar 08, 2015 4:33:24 AM org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version <clinit>
INFO: HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.0.0.Final
Mar 08, 2015 4:33:24 AM com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.ResourceAdapter start
INFO: MQJMSRA_RA1101: GlassFish MQ JMS Resource Adapter: Version:  5.1  (Build 9-b) Compile:  July 29 2014 1229
Mar 08, 2015 4:33:24 AM com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.ResourceAdapter start
INFO: MQJMSRA_RA1101: GlassFish MQ JMS Resource Adapter starting: broker is REMOTE, connection mode is TCP
Mar 08, 2015 4:33:24 AM com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.ResourceAdapter start
INFO: MQJMSRA_RA1101: GlassFish MQ JMS Resource Adapter Started:REMOTE
Waiting for messages...
Received the following message: Testing, 1, 2, 3. Can you hear me?

Received the following message: Do you copy?

Received the following message: Good bye!

thufir@doge:~$
```

producer:

```
package net.ensode.glassfishbook;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.JMSContext;
import javax.jms.JMSProducer;
import javax.jms.Queue;

public class MessageSender {

    @Resource(mappedName = "jms/CrmConnectionFactory")
    //   @Resource(mappedName = "jms/GlassFishBookConnectionFactory")
    private static ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    @Resource(mappedName = "jms/CrmQueue")
    //   @Resource(mappedName = "jms/GlassFishBookQueue")
    private static Queue queue;

    public void produceMessages() {

        JMSContext jmsContext = connectionFactory.createContext();
        JMSProducer jmsProducer = jmsContext.createProducer();

        String msg1 = "Testing, 1, 2, 3. Can you hear me?";
        String msg2 = "Do you copy?";
        String msg3 = "Good bye!";

        System.out.println("Sending the following message: "
                + msg1);
        jmsProducer.send(queue, msg1);
        System.out.println("Sending the following message: "
                + msg2);
        jmsProducer.send(queue, msg2);
        System.out.println("Sending the following message: "
                + msg3);
        jmsProducer.send(queue, msg3);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MessageSender().produceMessages();
    }
}
```

consumer:

```
package net.ensode.glassfishbook;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.JMSConsumer;
import javax.jms.JMSContext;
import javax.jms.Queue;

public class MessageReceiver {

    @Resource(mappedName = "jms/CrmConnectionFactory")
    //@Resource(mappedName = "jms/GlassFishBookConnectionFactory")
    private static ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
    @Resource(mappedName = "jms/CrmQueue")
    // @Resource(mappedName = "jms/GlassFishBookQueue")
    private static Queue queue;

    public void getMessages() {
        String message;
        boolean goodByeReceived = false;
        JMSContext jmsContext = connectionFactory.createContext();
        JMSConsumer jMSConsumer = jmsContext.createConsumer(queue);
        System.out.println("Waiting for messages...");
        while (!goodByeReceived) {
            message = jMSConsumer.receiveBody(String.class);
            if (message != null) {
                System.out.print("Received the following message: ");
                System.out.println(message);
                System.out.println();
                if (message.equals("Good bye!")) {
                    goodByeReceived = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MessageReceiver().getMessages();
    }
}
```

There might be a misconfiguration in Glassfish, which was preventing the correct execution.  However, I don't think so, because I didn't touch the configuration of the PTP queue used here...