# How do I specify the connection URL to connect to a JMS server?

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb, jms, jndi

For a [JMS Point-to-Point producer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28877487/262852), as per page 203 of [Java EE 7 with GlassFish 4 Application Server](http://isbn.directory/book/978-1-78217-688-6), how is a remote lookup performed?  I want to specify an ip address, 192.168.1.3, for the this producer:

output, with **JNDI properties for a CORBA lookup** logged to the console:

```
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ appclient -client NetBeansProjects/JMSPTPProducer/dist/JMSPTPProducer.jar 
Mar 08, 2015 4:58:18 AM org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version <clinit>
INFO: HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.0.0.Final
Mar 08, 2015 4:58:18 AM com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.ResourceAdapter start
INFO: MQJMSRA_RA1101: GlassFish MQ JMS Resource Adapter: Version:  5.1  (Build 9-b) Compile:  July 29 2014 1229
Mar 08, 2015 4:58:18 AM com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.ResourceAdapter start
INFO: MQJMSRA_RA1101: GlassFish MQ JMS Resource Adapter starting: broker is REMOTE, connection mode is TCP
Mar 08, 2015 4:58:18 AM com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.ResourceAdapter start
INFO: MQJMSRA_RA1101: GlassFish MQ JMS Resource Adapter Started:REMOTE
{org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort=3700, java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS=pass123, org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost=localhost, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL=user1}
Sending the following message: Testing, 1, 2, 3. Can you hear me?
Sending the following message: Do you copy?
Sending the following message: Good bye!
thufir@doge:~$
```

Can I use the CORBA JNDI parameters, which are loaded from `jndi.properties`, and perhaps pass those values to ?

code:

```
package net.ensode.glassfishbook;

import static java.lang.StrictMath.log;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.JMSContext;
import javax.jms.JMSProducer;
import javax.jms.Queue;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

public class MessageSender {

    @Resource(mappedName = "jms/CrmConnectionFactory")
    //   @Resource(mappedName = "jms/GlassFishBookConnectionFactory")
    private static ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    @Resource(mappedName = "jms/CrmQueue")
    //   @Resource(mappedName = "jms/GlassFishBookQueue")
    private static Queue queue;

    public void produceMessages() throws NamingException {
        Context ctx = new InitialContext();
        System.out.println(ctx.getEnvironment().toString());
        JMSContext jmsContext = connectionFactory.createContext();
        JMSProducer jmsProducer = jmsContext.createProducer();
        String msg1 = "Testing, 1, 2, 3. Can you hear me?";
        String msg2 = "Do you copy?";
        String msg3 = "Good bye!";
        System.out.println("Sending the following message: "
                + msg1);
        jmsProducer.send(queue, msg1);
        System.out.println("Sending the following message: "
                + msg2);
        jmsProducer.send(queue, msg2);
        System.out.println("Sending the following message: "
                + msg3);
        jmsProducer.send(queue, msg3);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException {
        new MessageSender().produceMessages();
    }
}
```

I've been looking through this text book, and googling, but, pardon, I don't know how remote JMS lookups are achieved.

While I really like this fluffy/frodo [example](http://www.fluffycat.com/Java/JMS-With-A-Queue/), I'm not sure how to specify an ip address.

see also:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/820-7853/ghyco/index.html